# How to derive electrochemical two-electrode test strip op-amp voltage output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, electrode

I've been trying to understand the [following](https://ww) electrochemical test strip in a simplified self-biased configuration diagram:

[image: two electrode test strip]

It appears to be an inverting op amp filter circuit but then gain = - Rs/0 = infinity!!

Given it appears to be a unity gain op-amp based on Vout, there must be a matching impedance in the electrode strip (e.g. [link](https://www.gamry.com/application-notes/instrumentation/potentiostat-fundamentals/)) but I am lost as to how Maxim determines Vout.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @user263983 I don't think so, Vout = Vb + (IsrRs)

Comment: There is "Is", that will make Vout = Vb + Is x Rs, regardless of the gain, as long as the OPA covers the range. The circuit you draw is intended to measure the resistance of the TWO-...STRIP. So, Is = Vb / R_TWO..._STRIP.

Comment: Go look up transimpedance amplifier. It should all become clear when you do.